# And Operator in Criteria not working as expected for nested documents inside aggregation Spring Data Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to fetch total replies where read values for a replies is true. But I am getting count value as 3 but expected value is 2 (since only two read value is true) through Aggregation function available in Spring Data Mongo. Below is the code which I wrote:

```
Aggregation sumOfRepliesAgg = newAggregation(match(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("replies.repliedUserId").is(userProfileId),Criteria.where("replies.read").is(true))),
        unwind("replies"), group("replies").count().as("repliesCount"),project("repliesCount"));
AggregationResults<Comments> totalRepliesCount = mongoOps.aggregate(sumOfRepliesAgg, "COMMENTS",Comments.class);
    return totalRepliesCount.getMappedResults().size();
```

Using AND Operator inside Criteria Query and passed two criteria condition but not working as expected. Below is the sample data set:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c4ca7c94807e220ac5f7ec2"),
"_class" : "com.forum.api.domain.Comments",
"comment_data" : "logged by karthe99",
"totalReplies" : 2,
"replies" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "b33a429f-b201-449b-962b-d589b7979cf0",
        "content" : "dasdsa",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-01-26T18:33:10.674Z"),
        "repliedToUser" : "@karthe99",
        "repliedUserId" : "5bbc305950a1051dac1b1c96",
        "read" : false
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "b886f8da-2643-4eca-9d8a-53f90777f492",
        "content" : "dasda",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-01-26T18:33:15.461Z"),
        "repliedToUser" : "@karthe50",
        "repliedUserId" : "5c4bd8914807e208b8a4212b",
        "read" : true
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "b56hy4rt-2343-8tgr-988a-c4f90598h492",
        "content" : "dasda",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-01-26T18:33:15.461Z"),
        "repliedToUser" : "@karthe50",
        "repliedUserId" : "5c4bd8914807e208b8a4212b",
        "read" : true
    }
],
"last_modified_by" : "karthe99",
"last_modified_date" : ISODate("2019-01-26T18:32:41.394Z")
}
```

What is the mistake in the query that I wrote?

Comment: I find it easier to debug issues with aggregation queries if I can see the actual MongoDB query being generated by Spring Data. Adding the following to your `application.yml` file will enable logging of the MongoDB queries being generated: `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG`. If that doesn't help, please add the query from the log to your question.

Comment: The below code gave me the expected output:Aggregation sumOfRepliesAgg = newAggregation(unwind("$replies"),match(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("replies.repliedUserId").is(userProfileId),Criteria.where("replies.read").is(false))),
    group("replies").count().as("repliesCount"),project("repliesCount"));
  AggregationResults<Comments> totalRepliesCount = mongoOps.aggregate(sumOfRepliesAgg, "COMMENTS",
    Comments.class);
  return totalRepliesCount.getMappedResults().size();